# Change default shipping-information renderer template

Tags: magento-2.1, checkout, shipping

I am having the following issue:

I am trying to edit the default renderer template of shipping-information.

The default component is loading correctly and the custom template also, but i can't access the knockoutjs variable's like `address()`, is there any possibility i only add the custom template and use the default js file, or do i have to wrap or extend the js?

**My layout processor:**

```
<?php
class LayoutProcessor implements LayoutProcessorInterface
{
    /**
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function process($jsLayout)
    {
        $sidebarElements = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['sidebar']['children']['shipping-information']['children'];
    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['sidebar']['children']['shipping-information']['children'] = $this->setupSidebar($sidebarElements);

        return $jsLayout;
    }
    private function setupShipTo($sidebar)
    {
        $shipTo = [
            'ship-to' => [
                'config' => [
                    'template' => 'Guapa_Extension/shipping-information/address-renderer/default'
                ]
            ]
        ];

        return array_replace_recursive($sidebar, $shipTo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all after a lot of testing i figured out the templates of address renderer's doesn't work the default way through the layout processor. (DOOHHH after a lot of debugging)

So what did i do? i builded the following function in layoutProccesor.php:

```
<?php
private function setupShipTo($sidebar)
{
    $shipTo = [
        'ship-to' => [
            'rendererTemplates' => [
                'new-customer-address' => [
                    'config'    => [
                        'template' => 'Vendor_Module/module/shipping-information/address-renderer/default'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];

    return array_replace_recursive($sidebar, $shipTo);
}
```

As you can see i used the "rendererTemplates" item & edited the component block "new-customer-address" by setting the new template.

Also made sure the rendererTemplates get's added to the layout:

```
<?php
// Checkout sidebar
$sidebarElements = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['sidebar']['children']['shipping-information']['children'];
$jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['sidebar']['children']['shipping-information']['children'] = $this->setupSidebar($sidebarElements);
```